# Можно ли зарегистрировать dll в Windows, без прав администратора?

Tags: windows, dll

Можно ли зарегистрировать dll в системе на Windows (XP, Vista, 7), если нет прав администратора?

Comment: А как вы регистрируете, через консоль или из кода, или может другим способом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Регистрация библиотеки происходит посредством вызова:

```
RegSvr32.exe /i library.dll
```

RegSvr32.exe вызывает 1) LoadLibrary, 2) GetProcAddress, 3) DllRegisterServer. В свою очередь, DllRegisterServer обычно пишет в раздел HKLM реестра, что **невозможно** без прав администратора.

Подробнее о RegSvr32.exe - в [статье](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249873) MSDN.